# Распознование текста на картинке с белым шумом, openCV, pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

есть изображение с которого нужно получить текст к примеру такая картинка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но все мои попытки убрать белый шум были тщетны, вместе с ним стирается большая часть самого текста, что можете посоветовать в данной ситуации?

Comment: люди, которые могли бы вам что-то посоветовать могут подумать, что тот вариант решения, который они хотят предложить вы уже сами реализовали и отбросили... Советую привести в вопросе попытки собственных решений и описание подходов, которые  вы уже опробовали

Comment: Все мои попытки были настолько далеко от желаемого результата, что по итогу от самого изображения у меня оставался лишь 1 пиксель

Comment: начните [отсюда](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_non_local_means/py_non_local_means.html)